# InfoPath form web part connection to a list view web part

Tags: infopath, connected-web-parts

What value needs to be passed from a InfoPath form web part to a list view to display all items.

I have am InfoPath form displaying in a form web part that will pass a dropdown value into a list view web part and filter on the selected value.  It works perfectly!

Except...  I have not yet found a way to clear the filtered value to make the list show all values again.  The filter value stays in.

Does anyone know if there is a value that I can place in the dropdown list of values that will make the filter clear the value?

I've tried a blank entry and it doesn't clear anything out...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a button on the InfoPath Form with and action rule with two actions 1) add action to Set the dropdown field to a blank entry then 2)add action to 'Send data to Web Part' ... this sends the new cleared field to the connected list web part and the page refreshes.

I am assuming your dropdown field is the connected value.